# Communicating between parent window and popup window with different domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I am working with a browser extension with JavaScript.

What I have to do are:

- To pass some javascript objects from a webpage in "foo.com" to a
  popup webpage in "bar.com"
  Let's say, from
  "foo.com/some_page/" to "bar.com/another_page.html"
- To get the textarea in foo.com/some_page and control it in
  "bar.com/another_page.html"
  (Such as insert some text by
  clicking a button in "bar.com/another_page.html"

I have tried `window.opener` and `window.parent`, all I have got is the problem of Same-origin policy

Comment: The target page must have correct headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
Search on stackoverflow, this issue has been answered a lot of times

Answer (score 0):

It seems between two different hosts you are trying to access. Create a subdomain with `test.bar.com` and point the IP address of `foo.com`. Now insert below piece of code in your javascript. Hope it will work.

```js
document.domain = 'foo.com'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not own both foo.com and bar.com,
and bar.com is one of my github pages